# index counter for if conditions python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to generate some sort of cycle for my dataFrame. One cycle in the example below has the length of 4. The last column is how is supposed to look like, the rest are attempts on my behalf.

My current code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l = list(np.linspace(0,10,12))
data = [
        ('time',l),
         ('A',[0,5,0.6,-4.8,-0.3,4.9,0.2,-4.7,0.5,5,0.1,-4.6]),
         ('B',[ 0,300,20,-280,-25,290,30,-270,40,300,-10,-260]),
         ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(data))
length = len(df)
df.loc[0,'cycle']=1
df['cycle'] = length/4 +df.loc[0,'cycle']
i = 0
for i in range(0,length):
    df.loc[i,'new_cycle']=i+1
df['want_cycle']=   [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]  
print(length)
print(df)
```

I do need an if conditions in the code, too only increase in the value of df['new_cycle'] if the index counter for example 4. But so far I failed to find a proper way to implement such conditions.

Comment: Sorry @sulphur I'm a little confused, you only want to increase the count in new_cycle if the index is equal to 4?

Comment: no sorry only very 4, as you count to 4 and then increase i +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with the default range index, because your dataframe row index is a range starting with 0, the default index of a dataframe, you can use floor divide to calculate your cycle:

```
df['cycle'] = df.index//4 + 1
```

Output:

```
         time    A    B  cycle
0    0.000000  0.0    0      1
1    0.909091  5.0  300      1
2    1.818182  0.6   20      1
3    2.727273 -4.8 -280      1
4    3.636364 -0.3  -25      2
5    4.545455  4.9  290      2
6    5.454545  0.2   30      2
7    6.363636 -4.7 -270      2
8    7.272727  0.5   40      3
9    8.181818  5.0  300      3
10   9.090909  0.1  -10      3
11  10.000000 -4.6 -260      3
```

Now, if your dataframe index isn't the default, the you can use something like this:

```
df['cycle'] = [df.index.get_loc(i) // 4 + 1 for i in  df.index]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added just 1 thing for you, a new variable called new_cycle which will keep the count you're after.

In the for loop we're checking to see whether or not `i` is divisible by 4 without a remainder, if it is we're adding 1 to the new variable, and filling the data frame with this value the same way you did.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l = list(np.linspace(0,10,12))
data = [
        ('time',l),
         ('A',[0,5,0.6,-4.8,-0.3,4.9,0.2,-4.7,0.5,5,0.1,-4.6]),
         ('B',[ 0,300,20,-280,-25,290,30,-270,40,300,-10,-260]),
         ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(data))
length = len(df)
df.loc[0,'cycle']=1
df['cycle'] = length/4 +df.loc[0,'cycle']
new_cycle = 0
for i in range(0,length):
    if i % 4 == 0:
        new_cycle += 1
    df.loc[i,'new_cycle']= new_cycle
df['want_cycle'] = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]  
print(length)
print(df)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I just choose the answer above because it seems a more direct approach to solve my problem.